# Ideal setup for Rebus and RabbitMQ, non-durable messages, and request-reply peers

Tags: rabbitmq, rebus

I'm exploring using Rebus and RabbitMQ together to cover a couple of different scenarios.

**Scenario A**
I want to be able to have a central server push notifications to a list of arbitrary subscribers, but the messages don't need to be durable or persisted. If a subscriber is connected, they should receive a notification, but if they disconnect, then there's no need to queue a message for any client.

In my tests so far, I'm able to get a producer and consumer communicating with `UseRabbitMqInOneWayMode()` and `ManageSubscriptions()`, however, the messages build up in RabbitMQ when there are no subscribers, or if a subscriber disconnects. I've tried setting the header to false for `RabbitMqMessageQueue.InternalHeaders.MessageDurability`, but it has no effect. I suspect it's because the default queue that Rebus sets up is durable. Is there a way within Rebus to control this behavior?

**Scenario B**
As clients come online, or disconnect, I'd like to setup a request/reply channel between clients. For example:

1. Client A and client B connect
2. Client A will send a message requesting data that only Client B has. Client B gathers the info, and replies back to A.
3. Client B disconnects
4. Client A requests data from Client B, and should receive an error because B is no longer available.

What's the recommended config for this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on RabbitMQ, and so the Rebus support for RabbitMQ mostly comes from community contributions.

I think scenario A can be solved pretty easily though by using the RabbitMQ concept of "auto-delete queues", which you can configure with Rebus like this:

`Configure.With(...)
    .Transport(t => t.UseRabbitMq(...)
                     .ManageSubscriptions()
                     .AutoDeleteInputQueue())
    .(..)`

which causes RabbitMQ to delete the queue when the last subscriber disconnects.

In scenario B it sounds to me like you would be better off with something that is meant for synchronous communication, because that's what you really want. I suggest you use HTTP because it's pretty good at doing request/reply :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @mookid8000, `.AutoDeleteInputQueue()` was exactly what I was looking for. I'll put some more thought into how to approach scenario B, but this gets me pretty far along. Thanks!

Comment: @mookid8000 I'm unable to find AutoDeleteInputQueue on Rebus2. Was it removed?

Comment: Unfortunately, Yes... it was a complex thing to support

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was considering using this functionality to have non-persistent queues for very volatile subscriber nodes. For instance a scenario where I need an event to be delivered to all machines in a cluster, however the machines are created and destroyed on a regular basis.

Comment: @mookid8000 Are you planning to support this feature in future? It's very useful.